# Deleting rows satisfying certain conditions in R

Tags: r

I have a table Y, comprising of 6 columns. (Date, hour, min , sec , price, size).
So now i am supposed to delete entries which have time greater than 4 pm. the entire row of entries must be omitted. I am not quite sure how to proceed with this. So basically we will be looking at the hour column and making the comparison. 
ex:

```
Date       hour min sec price size
jan1st     9    45  45  345   100
jan1st     10   23  33  324   20
jan1st     11   02  34  434   10
jan4th     16   05  09  32    23 
jan5th     23   08  23  12    90
```

So in the above table, I would like to delete the entry that has 16 and 23 under the hours. and hence get rid of the entire row. How would i do that?

Comment: Hey I see you're new to SO.  I suggest that you provide a reproducible example (ie a minimal data set and the code to reproduce the error).  Also this is a fairly often asked question so you may want to search the archives first.

Answer (score 0):

First off, welcome to SO and R.  I'd suggest reading a few of the intro guides to getting started in R. [here for example](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html&sa=U&ei=aymHT5v-BsLTiAKd-ugG&ved=0CBAQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNH3e4EKklCKXUxpMRsapPNaY7t4kg) as they will answer many of these questions for you.

You need to use `[` which is the subset "function" as per my example below.  Also, as Tyler mentioned in the comments, if you use something like `dput` it is quick and easy for people to use your example data.

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(Date = c("jan1st", "jan1st", "jan1st", "jan4th", 
"jan5th"), hour = c(9L, 10L, 11L, 16L, 23L), min = c(45L, 23L, 
2L, 5L, 8L), sec = c(45L, 33L, 34L, 9L, 23L), price = c(345L, 
324L, 434L, 32L, 12L), size = c(100L, 20L, 10L, 23L, 90L)), .Names = c("Date", 
"hour", "min", "sec", "price", "size"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))



> dat[dat$hour < 16,]
    Date hour min sec price size
1 jan1st    9  45  45   345  100
2 jan1st   10  23  33   324   20
3 jan1st   11   2  34   434   10
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Mine is a huge dataset with about 15,000 rows. Would i be able to make use of this approach?

Comment: 15k rows isn't huge by any means! This will work just fine for that.